# Ошибка в layout-файле на API16

Tags: java, android, coordinator-layout

Здравствуйте.

На Android выше 5.0 все работает отлично, но стоило запустить программу на API 16, сразу получил ошибку.

Программа жалуется на Layout файл main_activity. Скажите, пожалуйста, что не так?

Layout-файл:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="15dp"
        app:title="Подсказки">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="none"
            android:id="@+id/imgV1" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/main.toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                >
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>




    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:background="#F5F5F5"
        >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/pagerMain"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/statCont"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:visibility="invisible">

    </LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_main"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_timeline_white_24dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/main.appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Логи:

```
    Exception while inflating <vector>
                                                                                org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17<vector> tag requires viewportWidth > 0
at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateStateFromTypedArray(VectorDrawableCompat.java:535)
at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.inflate(VectorDrawableCompat.java:472)
at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.createFromXmlInner(VectorDrawableCompat.java:436)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager$VdcInflateDelegate.createFromXmlInner(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:829)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:303)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:178)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:173)
at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawable(TintTypedArray.java:60)
at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:254)
at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:196)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:226)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createViewFromTag(AppCompatViewInflater.java:175)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:146)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:963)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1022)
at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:675)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
at com.evgeny.manko.egeshka.start.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    04-10 17:08:35.206 9061-9061/com.evgeny.manko.egeshka D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    04-10 17:08:35.206 9061-9061/com.evgeny.manko.egeshka W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a122a0)
    04-10 17:08:35.227 9061-9061/com.evgeny.manko.egeshka E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.evgeny.manko.egeshka/com.evgeny.manko.egeshka.start.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                             Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
at com.evgeny.manko.egeshka.start.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129) 
at com.evgeny.manko.egeshka.start.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                             Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020016
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1923)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:659)
at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.superGetDrawable(TintResources.java:48)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.onDrawableLoadedFromResources(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:374)
at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.getDrawable(TintResources.java:44)
at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:323)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:180)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:173)
at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawable(TintTypedArray.java:60)
at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:254)
at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:196)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129) 
at com.evgeny.manko.egeshka.start.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                             Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17: invalid drawable tag vector
                                                                                at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:877)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:818)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1920)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:659) 
at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.superGetDrawable(TintResources.java:48) 
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.onDrawableLoadedFromResources(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:374) 
at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.getDrawable(TintResources.java:44) 
at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:323) 
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:180) 
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:173) 
at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawable(TintTypedArray.java:60) 
at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:254) 
at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:196) 
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129) 
at com.evgeny.manko.egeshka.start.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
```

Answer (score 3):

Мое предположение, что у вас для FloatingActionButton ресурс иконки является vector, выглядит это примерно так

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="268.765"
android:viewportWidth="268.765" android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<path android:fillColor="#D80027" android:pathData="ourPathData ....."/>
```

```
android:src="@drawable/ic_timeline_white_24dp"
```

Для поддержки vector drawable на устройсвах с апи < 21 вам нужно добавить в gradle `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` подробнее об этом можно посмотреть тут http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html иначе на на версиях андроид < 21 у вас vector drawable не будет работать.

Comment: Ресурс иконки не векторный( Вообще векторных изображений в проекте нет. Были эксперименты с ними, но потом все удалил

Comment: попробуйте тогда сделать build clean, они могли остаться в сгенерированных папках